# Location service works in emulator but not on real android device?

Tags: android

I would like to get location of user, so I have this code:

```
LocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

        Log.d("locationManager ", "locationManager ");

        /*
         * try to get last know location
         */
        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location=location;
```

and than I send geo fix:

```
geo fix -122.41914 37.77919
```

it works fine in emulator, but when I try on on real device. it doesn't work, and I see the GPS icon blinking on device. Notice: GPS is enabled on device.

my question is:

- Do I need to sign application first, or put it on Google Play in order for app to work on device. Because I just sent the app to device by email.
- do you have a link of working example of location service so that I could install and test on device to see if it's behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your device can take a very long time to get a GPS fix. You may have to wait a few minutes (the blinking GPS icon means that the device is trying to get a GPS fix).

Comment: Thanks you ... it's abit strange because I already developed same application on iPhone, and in iPhone I get GPS fix quickly.

Comment: It really depends on a lot of things. I doubt the hardware is better on the iPhone, sometimes its because of weather/clouds, where you were, when the last time you got a fix was.